# Playing an MP4 or MP3 from a Link within an Android WebView

Tags: jquery, android, webview, mp3, hyperlink

I have searched far and wide and can't seem to find the exact answer or even close.

I have a WebView that opens a webpage (JQuery Mobile) and all is well.

Within that page there are static links to both mp3 and mp4 files.
The idea is that when clicked - the device will open the default sound or movie app to play each. This works when using the Android browser without issue.

When I open inside WebView, and click the same links - nothing happens.
Nothing opens, or plays.

I'm setting getSettings as wide open as I can.

```
**web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    web.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    web.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    web.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);**
```

I'll also note that I believe "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" only works on the initial URL loaded in the WebView. This is a link inside that WebView - so does not seem to work.

I had tried that.

Any ideas on how to enable the user the ability to click a link within a WebView and open the associate application as the browser does?

Much Appreciated!

/r

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok - found the answer after much searching on different topics.

The answer lies in intercepting the link as such:

```
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".mp3")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "audio/*");
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);   
            return true;
        } else if (url.endsWith(".mp4") || url.endsWith(".3gp")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);   
                return true;
        } else {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
     }
```

Comment: thank's Robbe I wanted to play streaming mp3 from my app in default player and its working fine :) , but as soon i backpress it stops playing and return to my app. I there any way to play it in background ??

Comment: when it call or how to call this method from webview?

Answer (score 0):

you will use an interface that loads a new Activity with a VideoView that executes the media link and blah blah blah....but i think this is the easy way to do it...

```
WebView WebContent = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

String htmlLink= "<a href=\"http://prueba.agenciareforma.com/webs/elnorte/blackberry/mp3/uno.mp3\">Open Mp3 here!</a>";

        WebContent.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,  htmlLink, "text/html", "utf-8", null);                
        WebSettings webSettings = WebContent.getSettings();
        webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

**UPDATE::**
change::

```
<a href="planetofrock.com/samples/lballad.mp3">Click Here</a>
```

to::

```
<a href="http://planetofrock.com/samples/lballad.mp3">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Appreciate - will give it a shot.

Comment: This is bit different. In the webpage I am trying to load, the link is on the page itself. The example above is geared towards opening an mp3 link from within the WebView itself. The two are separate. The WebView opens the page (html), and the page offers an link similar to above (..<a href="theSite.com/file.mp3">Click Here<....). I am looking for a solution to open that link from within the page that is in the WebView. Works fine in the Android native browser. Thanks...

Comment: mmm i think what you are describing here must be work!, whats the link of your page?

Comment: It's a client page so I can't share. But easy to recreate. Make a simple page with a simple link to an mp3 in it. Example: <a href="http://www.planetofrock.com/samples/lballad.mp3">Click Here</a>. Then when that's up on a server, make a WebView and launch it: **web.loadUrl("www.yourtestpage.com/test.html") I am unable to get the mp3 to launch in WebView - but works perfectly in the native Android browser. Any ideas - I have to be missing something simple.... Thanks.

Comment: ahh - sorry - no that was the limitation of the reply box. the lack of HTTP - my original had it - but the comment box stripped it. It is on the original html file on the server, and works fine when not in WebView (i.e. works from Android browser). The WebView is loading the overall HTML URL to the start page that has the link on it. Still can't even get it to open. I'd like it to open music player app.

Comment: Ok, still not working. I have tracked down a few other posts asking the same, but in each case - no one answered. 

I know this has to be a larger scale issue. Can an mp3 or mp4 link from a web page be opened from that webpage if it is within a WebView? 
Jorgesys, in your example, you opened the mp3 by using **String htmlLink**. In my case, I have no control over opening anything other than the base HTML page. The HTML page contains the links. 
Again - I want to stress the mp3 and mp4 links on the HTML page open fine in the browser, I just can't get them to open in the WebView.

Comment: Here is another example: `web.loadUrl("http://www.wyntonmarsalis.org/2005/07/20/listen-to-mp3-samples-from-the-new-wyntons-album");` Try loading that in a WebView and see if the mp3 links can open. This is the crux of my problem. They highlight as links, but do not open the native musicplayer app. Open that link in the Android web browser, and they do open the musicplayer app... Why?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar page which is loading a URL and that URL contains a link to play the audio in it.Its working fine for the first time but second time it doesn't play. the code for webview is:

```
WebSettings webSettings = this.webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
this.webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
this.webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

on my page I have audio tag like

```
<audio id="audiotag1"  style="display:none" preload="auto" hidden='true' autostart='false'>
    <source src="../../Content/sound/NewOrder.wav" type="audio/x-wav"> 
</audio>
```

and I am playing it through JQuery by calling its method

```
$('#audiotag1').play();
```

Hope it will work for you.